# Is there any way to install Internet Explorer 9 on Windows

Tags: internet-explorer-9

Client site has reported one issue on IE9 ... And we don't have Windows 7 or Vista to install it .

I have an option to test it on browserstack but its not efficient way to test on IE9 .

Is there any way to install Internet Explorer 9 on Windows . Please Let me know

Comment: Yes - see [this screenshot](http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Datei:Windows_Internet_Explorer_9_2011-03-15.png&filetimestamp=20110315224454). Seriously - **which** Windows?

Comment: You can go out and download IE9 from the Microsoft website. If you are using Windows XP however, it will not run IE9. Could you please make your question more descriptive?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you mean "Windows XP", then no, you can't install IE9.