# Is there any way to install Internet Explorer 9 on Windows

Tags: internet-explorer-9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to install Internet Explorer 9 on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/358476/is-there-any-way-to-install-internet-explorer-9-on-windows)

Client site has reported one issue on IE9 ... And we don't have Windows 7 or Vista to install it .

I have an option to test it on [browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com) but its not efficient way to test on IE9 .

Is there any way to install Internet Explorer 9 on Windows .

Please Let me know .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: IE9 works only on Win 7/Vista SP2/2008 SP2/2008 R2. You'll have to upgrade or use a third party service.

Comment: I am going to assume Windows XP or earlier, since you did not include that information. @Nacereddine seems to have answered your question.

Comment: @Vik/Varun: Please use **one** account for all your StackOverflow/SuperUser/... activities. You can manage them from the "accounts" tab on your user page.